# Workflow Rule Migration

Tags: workflow, process-builder

There is a trailhead head module on migration of workflows to Process builder. In that i am not able to understand some terminology. Need help

[Link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/workflow_migration/units/workflow_migration_criteria)

In this What is the meaning of "Top Account" no description is give on it. What I think it should be a checkbox but not sure

Answer (score 1):

It is the name of a node in each of the processes mentioned in the page. Do a search for "Top Account" on the webpage and you will see 12 instances of it.

It is a poorly-written trailhead page, so your confusion is understandable. You will, it seems, need a checkbox on the Account object in order to follow along completely with the examples given.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it means a checkbox field with name Top Account.
Incase you cannot find under accounts field then you need to create one and proceed with the trailhead.